# Is it possible to print one item legend item in italic in print composer?

Tags: qgis, printing, legend

Is it possible to have one item in italic font (species names) and the rest in "normal"? 
I use QGIS 2.6.

The legend consists of two items which should be written normal (trap positions and vegetation) and one should be in italic, as it is convention that Latin species names are written in italic fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the Item Font of a legend by clicking the Item Font button in the Legend Item properties:

[image]

However, this is going to edit **ALL** items in your legend.

So a solution/workaround - use two legends

Below I have added two legends one for each layer, and made the items normal in the top legend and italic in the bottom legend.  They are in fact two legends, but on my print composition, they appear to be in the same legend.  I removed the title and background from the bottom legend so it can appear as if it is apart of the top legend.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I also used this workaround. So there is (at moment) not real solution?

Comment: From the looks of it, I don't see an easy or intuitive "real" solution.